# В чём заключается ошибка? (PDOException)

Tags: mysql, yii2, pdo

Yii2. Пытаюсь вывести данные на экран из б/д, как показано в https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-databases.md 
В итоге:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

phpinfo() показало, что у меня установлен pdo_mysql, не знаю в чём дело. Помогите.

Comment: У вас конфигурация для соединения с БД прописана? Покажите

Comment: <?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=basic/web;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];

Comment: там я поменял только localhost на basic/web

Comment: `там я поменял только localhost на basic/web` - зачем?

Comment: Вместо `basic/web` пропишите `127.0.0.1` и проверьте что пароль и логин к БД правильные

Comment: @XYZ собсн, `localhost` тоже должен работать. Просто автор зачем-то решил его сменить на другое значение

Comment: Попробуй отключи PDO в PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

Я понял свою ошибку. Не нужно было менять имя сервера с "localhost" на "basic/web". И с "127.0.0.1" всё отлично работает, то есть база данных подключается.